# Legendary portals don't work anymore

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

My game isn't letting me catch the legionaries Azelf, Uxie, and Terrakion. I've checked, double checked, and triple checked, I'm getting all of the requirements. but it's not letting me battle, I can get to the portal and I have defeated the elite four again but I get the same results

Comment: Are you doing everything right? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203544/87579

Comment: If you've accidentally fainted them, you may need to re-battle the Elite 4/Champion for them to reappear. Otherwise, look at the prerequisites I've listed on the answer pinckerman listed above^

Comment: @pinckerman - the portals don't dissappear, but they won't activate if you don't meet the requirements

Comment: @pinckerman - Oh, it was just the way you worded it. You can still find some legendary portals without meeting the requirements, or at a different time of day for example, but the portal will not activate

Comment: Haha fair enough