# What is the easiest way to catch all the legendary pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have played pokemon for a while, and i never seem to be able to find all the legendary pokemon. I am looking for the best and easiest ways to do this.

Comment: If you mean where to find them and which prerequisites you need, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203543/what-are-the-prerequisites-to-encounter-the-legendaries-in-oras).

Comment: Are you asking about "catching" them, or "finding" them, or both?

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1: Prepare a "catching" pokemon**

This is one of the most important parts which can make catching legendaries easy or painful. With a catching pokemon, i mean a pokemon with moves which are specifically designed so that the enemy pokemon shows almost no resistance when trying to catch it. I'll post my catching pokemon here:

```
Gothitelle @ Leftovers
Ability: Shadow Tag
Nature: Modest
EV: 252 KP | 252 Sp. Atk | 6 Init
Moves:
- Thunder Wave
- Heal Block
- Psychic
- HP (Fire)
```

So, the EV don't really matter. I just like to train my pokemon correctly, even if I only use them offline. So the purpose of this little guy is:

```
- Prevent the enemy from running away via shadow tag
- Paralyse him in the beginning of the fight
- Block every form of heal via Heal Block (Mewtwo or Lugia can be a pain)
- Deal damage with the other 2 moves
```

Catching legendaries with this setup is not really difficult.

**Step 2: Get the Location**

Find them. You need to know the location, obviously. There are various websites where you can look them up.

**Step 3: Get some balls!**

No, not these Balls. I'm talking about pokeballs. I had the situation a few times where i encountered a legendary with like 4 or 5 balls left. I'd recommend the following balls:

- 1 x Quick Ball
- 10 x Ultra Balls / 10 x Dusk Ball if you play at night or in a cave
- endless Timer Balls

**Step 4: Catch it**

So, here we are, got all our preparations complete, ready to catch it. In the first turn, you throw the quick ball. I had some fights where the legendary was caught in the first turn with it since it got a catch rate of 5x in the first turn. It's surely worth a try.

If it didn't work out, try to weak it with your moves. Paralyse is the best thing to do in my opinion, since it slows the enemy, increases your catch rate, sometimes doesn't let him attack and will not be removed with time like sleep. If it is low enough, you can start throwing your ultra balls/dusk balls at it. If they are gone, the 13th round passed, which is the point where your timer balls got the max catch rate of 4x. Now you just continue throwing timer balls at it until you caught it. Ofc, if you play with heal block, you have to recast the move, if you play without, you might have to weak it again if it heals itself.

Hope this helped or even answered your question.^^

Comment: I haven't played pokemon for long time, but you did a great answer covering all the basic concepts. I really like it. Congrats

Comment: If the formula on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball#Timer_Ball) is correct, the 10th round has already the maximum of 4x rate.

Comment: Instead of an Ultra Ball (2x rate), you can also use a Dusk Ball (3.5x rate, if in a cave or at night). I didn't catch all legendaries in ORAS, but I think there are quite some in a cave. Then you can maybe catch it a bit quicker. Other then that, excellent answer. +1!

Comment: @Mathias711 Yeah, that was the formula in Gen III and IV, but i think they changed it in V, so the 13. round is the one with the highest catch rate. And you're right, i completely forgot about the dusk balls, I'll add it right now, thank you!

Comment: Good point! Most legendary pokemon are in caves, and you can ALWAYS catch them at night. Cant belive I forgot about that! Thanks for the info and answers. You guys rock!

Comment: A pokemon with False Swipe can be very useful too!

Answer (score 3):

Heavy Balls are a better option than timer balls of the pokemon's weight is >451.5lbs

All legendaries have catch rate 3 which after timer ball turns to 12.

Heavy ball can change this to anywhere from 23 to 43 depending on the legendary's weight.

All legendaries are usually [quite] heavy.

Comment: This question is tagged [pokemon-oras], so Heavy Balls don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to catch legendaries in ORAS is to catch an Absol on Route 120 and teach it *Swords Dance*, *Double Team* and *False Swipe*. False Swipe is given to you by the man wearing glasses in the pokémart of Rustoboro city, the other moves are gotten by level up. Then give Absol the Absolite and level it up to at least level 60.

When in battle with a legendary, mega evolve and use Double Team 6 times followed by 3 Sword Dance, then False Swipe until the legendary reduced to 1 hp. Now throw tons of Ultra Balls at your desired legendary until you catch it.

Another thing to note is that Absol is a Dark type and most legendaries know a Psychic move which essentially gives you a free turn.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pokemon that is about ten levels over the legendary, and teach it false swipe. Also by tons of ultra balls (not timer balls because their catching rate is lower) The minimum amount of ultra balls you should have is twenty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really cheap, and you have a Master Ball, use it for a guaranteed catch. However, this is seen as a very easy way to capture a Legendary, and should only be left for absolute emergencies, as you're rarely ever able to get more than one (or two in the case of Black2/White2, but this is about ORAS) without getting extremely lucky.

Otherwise, using the correct type of Pokéball depending on the Legendary and also the turn helps out. As for moves, if you can get a move which inflicts a non-damaging status ailment like Sleep or Paralysis, then inflicting it will cause the catch rate to improve. False Swipe is also a godsend, as it allows you to make sure you don't accidentally knock out the Pokémon you're trying to catch. And, Not Very Effective moves can be helpful in chipping down the health of a Legendary when low.

Finally, make sure that the Pokémons you choose to send out are not weak to the Legendary's attacks. Because then you're less likely to have them survive the fight.

Answer (score -1):

Yea. Use *plenty* of Timer Balls. That's how I caught Mewtwo. Never mind about HP restoring moves. It just increases the amount of turns you have. Oh, and buy a whole lot of Potions. Legendaries can be powerful damage wise. Just get at least 100 of the two so you never run out for a long time.