# Pokemon Alpha Sapphire- Fabled Cave not working

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

On Pokemon Alpha Sapphire I've been trying to collect the legendaries but it's not working. Some of the spots to find them are missing and sometimes the battle won't initiate. I'm currently having this problem with Zekrom.

I can get to the place, even though it doesnt show the mirage spot but it won't let me initiate the battle not matter how many times I engage the the mysterious ring. It just says, "A mysterious ring is floating in the air..."

I have two level 100 pokemon in my party and it still won't work. I've beaten the game, the delta episode and the Elite Four more than five times to level up my pokemon. This is my first time playing this game and I don't use hacks. I've looked everywhere to see if I was missing something and I'm not. I haven't fought Zekrom but it's acting like I have. Is this because I didn't catch Kyogre?

Edit: I do have the Eon-Flute and I have done the rematch with Kyogre and caught him.

Comment: Do you have the Eon-Flute? Steven gives it to you after you end the world-disaster (catching Kyogre/Groudon)

Comment: Just saw what your edit did. Yes it's because you haven't caught Kyogre, weren't awarded the Eon Flute and therefore did not meet the prerequisites for Zekrom to appear. I have rolled back the edit as that is vital info to have, given that it is the cause of your problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

Catching Reshiram / Zekrom has two prerequisites:

- Obtaining the Eon Flute (given to you by Steven after ending the world disaster & catching either Kyogre or Groudon depending on your version).
- Having 1 level 100 Pokemon in the party.

Assuming you've met these prerequisites, the only other reasons why Zekrom wouldn't appear in the Fabled Cave are:

- If you've previously caught it
- You've defeated it, and haven't re-battled the Elite Four
- You are playing Omega Ruby. Zekrom can only be caught on Alpha Sapphire.

Comment: I have previously written up a guide for meeting the prerequisites for the legendaries here: [What are the prerequisites to encounter the legendaries in ORAS?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203543/what-are-the-prerequisites-to-encounter-the-legendaries-in-oras)

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a portal somewhere in the Fabled Cave, and Zekrom will be on the other side.

Comment: That's the portal he's referring to when he says he receives the message "A mysterious ring is floating in the air..."

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that part.