# How come Cobalion and Virizion won't spawn in Omega Ruby?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have completed the game and I have 4 legendaries to catch.

These were Cresselia and the 3 deer trio, which are Terrakion, Cobalion, and Virizion.

I have 3 Pokemon with max EV and I caught Terrakion on a Tuesday.  A day later when I went back to the portal to them, which was when Cobalion was meant to be there, nothing happened.

I waited a day later and still, nothing happened. It just keeps saying that "a mysterious ring is floating in the air."

Please help, because I really want to catch Cobalion and Virizion and it isn't working!

Comment: Those 3 are commonly referred to as the "Swords of Justice", rather than the "deer trio".

Answer (score 4):

As per my answer here: [What are the prerequisites to encounter the legendaries in ORAS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203544/28182)

> #### Terrakion/Virizion/Cobalion
>
> - **Available on:** Both Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire
> - **Location:** Pathless Plain (Eon-Flute, Red Spark Near Pacifidlog Town)
> - **Required Party Pokemon:** 3 Pokémon fully EV-Trained (Obtained once a Pokémon's stats cannot be raised anymore.)
> - **Required Item:** None
> - **Date/Time available:**
>
>   - Terrakion - Tuesday/Saturday
>   - Virizion - Monday/Thursday
>   - Cobalion - Sunday, Wednesday and Friday

If you've met all the prerequisites, then you should first confirm the date/time on your 3DS. Ensure that it is set to the correct day for them to spawn. **If you change the date/time on the 3DS, all time based events (including legendary spawns) will be disabled for 24-48 hours**.

If your 3DS is correct and there have been no time/day based changes in the past 24-48 hours, then the only other cause for them not appearing is that you've **previously fought them.** You will need to re-defeat the Elite Four in order to have them spawn again.

Comment: I did put my time on my 3ds an hour forward because it was wrong and I have also defeated the elite four three times.

Comment: @Sharkman - well then you'll need to wait 24-48 hours before they spawn again. And any time you defeat them instead of catch them, you will need to rebattle the elite four to have them reappear :-)

Comment: By waiting 24-48 hours to I have to wait without going on my 3ds or can I still play and if I change the time back to what it originally was will it work. Because pathless plains is still there but it just keeps saying a mysterious ring is floating in the air I will defeat the elite four and see if it was that.

Comment: @Sharkman, you can continue to play, but any time based event (daily battles with rivals, berries growing, legendary spawn times etc) are disabled. Changing your clock back will only reset the 24-48hr cooldown, so I wouldn't bother with that. Pathless plain will still exist as will the ring, it's just that legendaries will not appear when they should.

Comment: Also, in the general case it will only be 24 hours. Its only longer if you set the clock to a weird time such that it won't be ready until after two 'sleeps' per se. Generally speaking, you should only have to wait a day.

Comment: Ok thx its working again I caught cobalion

Comment: @Sharkman - glad I could help. You can mark the answer as accepted if you want, by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. This lets other people know that the answer worked for you, as well as awarding me (and you) some extra reputation points :-).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the elite 4 again you could just save before and just soft reset it  you fail to capture them